# How to redefine the + operator on Arrays in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, addition

Assuming points are represented using JavaScript `Array` as `[x,y]`, how could I define the `+` operator on points such that:

```
[1,2] + [5,10] == [6,12]
```

Comment: You don't. Even if operator overloading was possible, and you could do it ad-hoc for existing types, you shouldn't because it breaks a lot of code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JavaScript does not have a facility for overriding the built-in arithmetic operators.

There are some limited tricks you can pull by overriding the `.valueOf()` and `.toString()` methods, but I can't imagine how you could do what you're asking.

You could of course write a function to do it.

Answer (score 2):

How about a nice 'plus' method?
This doesn't care how many indexes either array has,
but any that are not numeric are converted to 0.

```
Array.prototype.plus= function(arr){
    var  L= Math.max(this.length,arr.length);
    while(L){
        this[--L]= (+this[L] || 0)+ (+arr[L] || 0);
    }
    return this;
};

[1, 2].plus([5, 10])

/*  returned value: (Array)
[6,12]
*/

[1, 2].plus([5, 10]).plus(['cat',10,5])

/*  returned value: (Array)
6,22,5
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that's **not exactly what you want** to do but a solution to your problem is to do something like that:

```
var arrayAdd = function() {
    var arrays = arguments,
        result = [0, 0];

    for( var i = 0, s = arrays.length; i < s; i++ ) {
        for( var j = 0, t = arrays[ i ].length; j < t; j++ ) {
            result[ j ] += parseInt( arrays[ i ].shift(), 10 );
        }
    }

    return result;
};

var sum = arrayAdd( [1,2], [5,10] ); //Should return [6, 12]

console.log( sum );
```

PLease note that this code is not final. I see some problems:

1. The initial value of the result array should be dynamic
2. I haven't tested the code if the arrays aren't of equal length

Good luck!

Comment: Hmm, according to your reputations @Misha, you must have thought about that solution already. :\